# Python user input eval error

Tags: python

Hi i'm new to python programming and i was trying to put together a small snippet to see how things work but i guess there is something wrong with my code :

```
users = []
while True:
    new_user = input("Enter a user")
    if new_user == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        users.append(new_user)

for user in users:
    print(user)
```

the error i get is like so :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mark/workspace/Gest/launcher.py", line 4, in <module>
    new_user = input("Enter a user")
  File "/root/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.3.0.201508182223/pysrc/pydev_sitecustomize/sitecustomize.py", line 141, in input
    return eval(raw_input(prompt))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'david' is not defined
```

Comment: Use `raw_input()`, Assuming that you are using `Python 2.x`.

Comment: Seems to be Python 2.x, but then it would be better to use `print user` and not `print(user)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inspecting the code it seems that you are using Python 2.x, and in 2.x `input()` is actually used to evaluate the input by the user, so you must use `raw_input()` to take input from the user, keeping in mind that `raw_input()` always returns a string.

```
users = []
while True:
    new_user = raw_input("Enter a user")
    if new_user == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        users.append(new_user)

for user in users:
    print(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `raw_input()` rather than `input()`. The normal `input()` function takes python code, while `raw_input()` makes user input a `string`. Also might I suggest adding some more padding on your prompt to make it a tad more readable?

```
users = []
while True:
    new_user = raw_input("Enter a user: ")
    if new_user == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        users.append(new_user)

for user in users:
    print(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works on Python 3, but not Python 2. In Python 2, the text entered in response to the `input` function is evaluated as Python code and hence the error about `david` not being defined.

`raw_input` is what you want on Python 2.

See:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input

and:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

If you switch to Python 3, your code is correct as `input` in Python 3 is equivalent to `raw_input` in Python 2.

See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#input for the Python 3 documentation for `input`.